# How to get custom table values from a stored procedure in EF6?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I haven't work with EF 6 for a few years, and I am struggling to remember and do things that were trivial.

I have `MyStoredProc` that returns around 10 columns from multiple tables (ex `tb1.Col1, tb1.Col2, tb2.Col3, tb3.Col5, tb3.Col1`). There is no matching entity or a complex type in my `.EDMX` file.

If I get the return type of this stored procedure, it is an integer. I have been trying all day to add a new entity named `MyResult` with the correct columns, but still I cannot see than under the entity options when going "Add > Function Import".

I tried to add a complex type, `MyComplexType`, and while it appears under Complex Types for "Add > Function Import", then the model is not accessible in the code (ex `dbContext.MyComplexType`).

Read few tutorials online, but none that demonstrates how it is done.

We are using EF 6, .NET 4.8.2 and VS2019 Pro.

Can somebody please point me to the correct direction as I have already spent a day for something that should be an hour's work?

Comment: why using EF in this case, use ado.net with class

Answer (score 1):

Create an object that has the same property names as the results returned by the stored procedure in your case `tb1.Col1, tb1.Col2, tb2.Col3, tb3.Col5, tb3.Col1`.

For example for the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetResult]  
    @param int  
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        tb1.Col1 AS c1, 
        tb1.Col2 AS c2,
        tb2.Col3 AS c3,
        tb3.Col5 AS c4,
        tb3.Col1 AS c5
    FROM 
        tb1
    ....
    WHERE clause
END
```

create a class that looks like this:

```
public class Result
{
    public string c1 { get; set; }
    public string c2 { get; set; }
    public bool c3{ get; set; }
    public string c4 { get; set; }
    public bool c5{ get; set; }
}
```

and then call the procedure like this:

```
using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var Parameter = new SqlParameter("@param", 4);

    var result = context.Database
                        .SqlQuery<Result>("GetResults @param", Parameter)
                        .ToList();
}
```

The result will contain a list of `Result` objects. You can call `SqlQuery` using as many parameters as needed.

Comment: Thank you marc_s for the reply. That worked, but I would like to have the option to execute it directly, not using SqlQuery. I know it is possible, but I am missing some details.